# Repository Pattern Null Reference Exception in Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I have Implemented a Generic Repository Pattern and UnitOfWork but I get a Null Reference Exception in my Controller when I try to populate a new instance of a Model Class.

Here is my Repository Pattern:

```
class GenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    internal PropmetEntities context;
    internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

    public GenericRepository(PropmetEntities context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get()
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;
        return query.ToList();
    }

    public virtual TEntity GetByID(object id)
    {
        return dbSet.Find(id);
    }

    public virtual void Insert(TEntity entity)
    {
        dbSet.Add(entity);
    }

    public virtual void Delete(object id)
    {
        TEntity entityToDelete = dbSet.Find(id);
        Delete(entityToDelete);
    }

    public virtual void Delete(TEntity entityToDelete)
    {
        if (context.Entry(entityToDelete).State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            dbSet.Attach(entityToDelete);
        }
        dbSet.Remove(entityToDelete);
    }

    public virtual void Update(TEntity entityToUpdate)
    {
        dbSet.Attach(entityToUpdate);
        context.Entry(entityToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
}
```

Here is my unit of work:

```
class UnitOfWork 
{
    private PropmetEntities context = new PropmetEntities();
    private GenericRepository<User> userRepository;

    public GenericRepository<User> UserRepository
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.userRepository == null)
                this.userRepository = new GenericRepository<User>(context);
            return userRepository;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my Model Class:

```
public class UserGridModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Username {get; set;}
    public string EMail { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public ContactInformation ContactInformation { get; set; }
    public Role Role1 { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my controller action:

```
private UnitOfWork.UnitOfWork unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork.UnitOfWork();

    [PrivilegeFilter(priv = Privileges.UserView)]
    public ActionResult Grid(GridSettings set)
    {
        var userList = from user in unitOfWork.UserRepository.Get() select user;
        var users = new List<UserGridModel>();
        if (userList.Any())
        {
            foreach (var user in userList)
            {
                users.Add(new UserGridModel()
                {
                    ID = user.ID,
                    Username = user.Username,
                    EMail = user.ContactInformation.EMail,
                    Surname = user.ContactInformation.Surname,
                    Role = user.Role1.Description
                });



            }
        }

        GridModel grid = new GridModel(set, users.Count());
        grid.rows = users.Skip((set.PageIndex - 1) * set.PageSize).Take(set.PageSize).ToList();
        return Json(grid, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

I get an Null Reference Exception here:

```
users.Add(new UserGridModel()
            {
                ID = user.ID,
                Username = user.Username,
                EMail = user.ContactInformation.EMail,
                Surname = user.ContactInformation.Surname,
                Role = user.Role1.Description
            });
```

Comment: You probably have user.ContactInformation == null.

Comment: Don't. Create. Generic. Repositories.

Comment: @Phill Can u please explain why Don't. Create. Generic. Repositories ?

Comment: Because IRepository<T> and GenericRepositor(ies) make assumptions about your domain. It assumes all objects have primary keys and never composite keys. That all can be created or updated, all can get or list. These are false assumptions. This is bad design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you have ContactInformation for the user ? My guess is user.ContactInformation is null and you are getting error when getting user.ContactInformation.Email.

Comment: My `ContactInformation` fields in the DataBase was empty. I just made them required fields when creating a new user so that they can't be null.

Answer (score 0):

Possible reasons are
`user.ContactInformation == null` or `user.Role1 == null`. You should add some check for nulls in your `UserGridModel` creation code.

Answer (score 0):

You could `null` check by doing something like this:

```
foreach (var user in userList.Where(x => x.ContactInformation != null && x.Role1 != null))
{
    users.Add(new UserGridModel()
    {
        ID = user.ID,
        Username = user.Username,
        EMail = user.ContactInformation.EMail,
        Surname = user.ContactInformation.Surname,
        Role = user.Role1.Description
    });
 }
```

This will at least prevent you from getting the *Null Reference Exception* when one of those properties is `null`.